# Bidirectional Single-Socket RPC interoperable between .net and C++

Tags: c++, .net

We have two softwares, on written in C++11 and one written in C#.net, which need to communicate which each other.
One should be the server (the C++ one) and the other one the client.

What I'd like is the benefits of WSDL and Websockets:

- Bidirectional communication with *one* socket (endpoint)
- service contracts which define operations

  - can be interpreted by C++ and .net libs
  - ideally can be used to create message stub classes
  - ... and features automatic serialization and deserialization

And this should integrate nicely and easily in C++ and C# development.
(For C#: WCF?!).

On the .net side, i think this could be achieved with .net 4.5 and a duplex-Websockets WCF with SOAP messaging.
But maybe there's better alternatives (which don't have as much overhead as SOAP XML messages).
However, i completely lack experience on the C++ side.

So I'm looking for standards which are interoperable between C++ and .net and libraries which help in seamlessly integrated these in C++/.net respectively. Free / opensource libraries are preferred.

I'm not expecting there to be a single library which handles both, the C++ and .net side.. ;-)